# Question is already fully answered, but is phrased in a more useful way for searching

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

A few months ago I answered a [question of the form "What does X do"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823157/what-is-the-purpose-of-namedarg-annotation-in-javafx-8) with an answer of the form "X is there to allow you to do Y".

Today another user posted the question ["How do I do Y?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331061/java-8-fxml-how-do-you-extend-a-class-that-cannot-have-the-default-constructor). Since the question already had a comprehensive answer, I marked it as a duplicate.

The poster of the second question pointed out that his/her version of the question was far more amenable to searching and would probably be usefully kept. This is actually a very good point, imo, as if you wanted the answer to the second question you would have no way of putting together a search that would find the original.

What is the correct thing to do?

1. Vote to re-open the second question, and then provide an answer, or just a comment, linking to the original?
2. Edit the title of the original question so that it is worded in a way more amenable to searching?
3. Something else I haven't thought of.

Comment: The point of closing as duplicate is so searchers finding the closed question by using different terms than the original question can still get to the original answer. Closing it doesn't delete it, and duplicates are often kept around as signposts to the good questions/answers that are similar. In other words, the newer question will already be "kept" for searchers, so no need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess I thought that the search algorithm might be weighted in favor of questions that weren't closed (or at least had answers), but you seem to imply that's not the case. Leaving it as is is presumably the most appropriate course of action then.

Comment: Nope, not the case. On top of that, a lot of searchers are going to go through Google or other search engines, and those don't care if a question is closed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct thing to do in these kinds of situations is nothing.

Closing as a duplicate is meant to make the closed question a signpost to the original question, and therefore the answer. Duplicates could be written in different terms which make it easier for anyone searching the topic to find their answers. While not all duplicates are useful, on smaller issues like this, they certainly are an will usually remain undeleted so they may serve as this signpost.

Search, both here and on the various search engines, doesn't really care if a question is closed- So long as it is relevant to your search query, you'll get that result somewhere down the line.

The only way the closure matters is if the searcher is not logged in. Since the second question does not have an answer, users that are not logged in or do not have an account will automatically be redirected from that link to the original post.